# Does changing a file's attribute also change its time stamps?

Tags: windows, ntfs

In Windows 8.0 it seems that when I change a file's attribute (e.g. H and R) the time stamps (Created, Modified, Accessed) stay the same.

Are file attributes in fact stored in the NTFS file system rather than the file itself? Shouldn't the time stamps change if you are changing the attributes of a file? Isn't that considered modifying the file? If I am not mistaken the time stamps are also stored in the NTFS file system, and not the file itself.

Is this also the case with FAT32 file system and previous versions of Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Windows NT has, since inception, supported both a Win32 subsystem and a POSIX subsystem.  In both Win32 and POSIX, files have three timestamps.  Two of those timestamps are common to Win32 and POSIX.  In Win32, files have **Creation**, **Last Write**, and **Last Access** timestamps.  POSIX has **Last Modified**, **Last Access**, and **I-node Changed** timestamps.

Windows NT, and NTFS, in order to support both Win32 and POSIX thus give files *four* timestamps: Creation, Last Write/Modified, Last Access, and Last Changed.

In POSIX, the I-node Changed timestamp reflects the time that something in the I-node — permissions, owner, group, and so forth — is changed.  Windows NT sets the timestamp even if the thing that is changed is changed from Win32, since (of course) both subsystems are layered over the native API when it comes to files.

So changing a file's attrtibutes — read-only, hidden, system, archive, index, offline, and so forth — with [`SetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365535(v=vs.85).aspx) will update its Last Changed timestamp.

It doesn't change the Last Write timestamp because that is only influenced by changes to a file's *data*.  It is changes to a file's *metadata*, in the I-node/MFT Record, that influence the Last Changed timestamp.

Every filesystem in Windows NT has to provide these four timestamps to the kernel.  That's the API that filesystem drivers have to implement.

But not all filesystems actually have them defined in the on-disc data structures, or have them defined to the same granularity as the Windows NT kernel does.  The FAT filesystem format, for example, originally only had *one* timestamp per file: its Last Write timestamp.  Windows NT's FAT filesystem driver, and the FAT filesystem driver in DOS+Windows 95/98/ME, used theretofore spare fields in directory entries for storing more timestamps.  But there wasn't room for all four.  There's no on-disc Last Change timestamp; the Last Access timestamp has a granularity of 1 day; and the Last Write and Creation timestamps have a granularity of 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

*Last modified* date refers to the date it was last Written. When the attributes are changed they don't affect the data that you stored in file, and therefor *Last modified* remains same.

*Created date* by definition is constant. *Last accessed* is unpredictable.

However there is another time stamp (*invisible in Explorer*) called MFT. When you change any property/attribute, MFT changes of course.

Comment: What are you referring to here? Personal experience? Can you post a link or something to prove this?

Comment: @Sammy I also had similar experience with my own files , so yes it includes personal experience. But for further documentation, read [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2009/10/16/the-four-stages-of-ntfs-file-growth.aspx), [this](http://whereismydata.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/dates-ntfs-created-modified-accessed-written/) and [this](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy06.htm)