# Does changing a NTFS readonly attribute rewrite the file?

Tags: ntfs

Does changing a NTFS readonly attribute rewrite the file?

I used this command to set readonly in every file recursively: `Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Alphabetic\W-Z\XYZ" -File -Recurse | foreach {$_.IsReadOnly = $true}` and it took a few minutes - much longer than I was expecting. Was it updating metadata within the file itself or in separate metadata file storage? Was each file's data being overwritten?

I read [Does changing a file's attribute also change its time stamps?](https://superuser.com/questions/718784/does-changing-a-files-attribute-also-change-its-time-stamps) but it was not clear to me whether that answered my question.

Comment: To my knowledge, your code should not update anything but stuff in memory. There's no set command issued, but maybe this works. In any case, this is not actually an NTFS attribute, but general file attribute. It also exists in FAT32 for example. A file attribute is like meta data, it does not change the content of a file, only an attribute in the database that tells where each file is located on your harddrive (eg, the FAT)

Comment: Okay, so this does indeed change the file attribute of a file. Just tested it like this: `(Get-Item -Path "file.txt").IsReadOnly = $true` and then used a `cmd` window and ran `attrib` on the file, it now is indeed read only. After running this, the following `(Get-Item -Path "file.txt") | fl *` shows that the file was not modified, which confirms that changing the attribute does not alter the content of the file in any way.

Answer (score 2):

No. File attributes that are set using the `cmd` command `attrib` (which is the same as what your powershell code does) are written in the file allocation table, not on the file itself.

Keep in mind that making small changes to a file can be fast to just one file, but can be slow if you do this to many files because it is much faster to make many changes to one file, than that it is to make one change to many files. Even for SSD's.